# Tabbed webpart with collapsible content

Tags: sharepoint-online, content

I'm trying to create a webpart with multiple tabs (which I've achieved) and within each of those tabs I'd like to be able to display collapsible content sections. I've figured out how to add a script for tabbed content, and in a seperate environment I've figured out how to create a collapsible content webpart; my problem is that I can't figure out how to combine them.

I need a solution that will work in sharepoint online.

Thanks

Comment: My assumption is that you are unable to combine both the functionality to work . This is more of constructing your html and javascript. Please post your exact part where you are struggling with the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption 1: you achieve the tabs by loading a JavaScript file. 
Assumption 2: you achieve the collapsible parts by calling a JavaScript function.

Put the JavaScript function for the collapsible content at the bottom of the JavaScript file for the tabs. Since the JS file is loaded for the tabs, it now also contains the functions that are called in for the collapsing.

If you need more help, post your scripts.